# Profile Cover Editing via Facebook's Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline, cover

I know that this question was raised out several times,
and I even read most of the questions regarding the topic.
But there was a gap of about a month till now, and I'd like to know if there is any process in changing the Timeline Cover picture from the api(via an app).
Do you know any new information about this?
Or is there a solution out there? (except for uploading to cover folder)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have seen a site which does retrieve your cover picture. I do not have any idea as to how they do it. But http://www.timelinemoviemaker.com/ have done that. So I guess there has to be a way out.

Comment: I found a way :) thanks anyways.

Comment: They can be retrieved but not edited

Comment: if you found a way adam360, could you post it here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, there´s no API support for it, but you can upload a photo and then redirect user to:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=PHOTO_ID

Comment: Sorry miss a point here. Suppose you redirect, and...? Will it affect an actual timeline photo in any way?

Comment: No... If PHOTO_ID is owned by the user, the link above will display the image as cover in preview mode. User can Save it or Cancel.

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no API to change the cover photo; i'm not aware of plans to change this

Comment: Thanks. Ill vote this as an answer if no updates will arrive soon.

Answer (score 2):

facebook does not allow an app to upload a picture to the profile album. that is sort of a security restriction and will apply to cover images too, i guess. so you can upload a picture to a new album or any other album, but NOT the profile or timeline cover album.

i doubt that facebook will ever change this, unfortunately.

Comment: well, there is a newer way to update the cover AND profile photo of a facebook page, but there is no way to update any of those for a user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Profile Timeline is not yet released for all, so maybe we won't be getting any access via graph api until facebook releases timeline for all.

Comment: I do have timeline enabled, in my profile. So can I code something to work with it?

Comment: You have the timeline enabled and some other's have it as well, but it's not officially enabled for all, so i do not think we will have any access to that until they enable timeline for all and nope, as of now there is no way to auto set your images as your cover using graph api, but you can upload an image on their profile and show them instructions on how to set that uploaded image as their cover image, recently we coded this for a client, have a look: http://bit.ly/omitBf