# Facebook timeline cover photo iphone

Tags: ios4, facebook-graph-api

How to set an existing album photo as timeline cover photo via api. I have seen apps that do this but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: I do not believe that there is anyway to change the cover photo though the API **yet**.  At least not a documented method.

Comment: See this post from a member of the developers support team at Facebook : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8070254/558021

Comment: possible duplicate of [Profile (timeline)Cover Edtiting via Api](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8070016/profile-timelinecover-edtiting-via-api)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Facebook timeline Image is same as changing the user profile image and Facebook does not allow to change the user's profile Picture or Facebook timeline Cover Image.

Please check these links: for timeline Cover Image [Profile Cover Editing via Facebook's Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070016/profile-timelinecover-edtiting-via-api), and for profile Image changing [Can I set a users profile image using the Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api).